# How to remove only 0-9 character long numbers from a file?

Tags: bash, sed, perl

How can we remove only the numbers that are 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 character long from a file? I mean the lines that are matching this pattern.

Example for removable lines:

```
cat input.txt
1
123423113
8372
8472323
```

Example for lines that shouldn't be removed:

```
cat input.txt
1a
1245d45
8565438753
b39592
3827495Hx
```

Comment: Are you waning lines that consist entirely of 1-9 digit numbers? Or  all 1-9 digit numbers? There's a critical difference. A line such as `foo 1234 bar` might be turned into `foo  bar`, or left alone depending on the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `sed`:

```
sed -i.bak -e '/^[0-9]\{1,9\}$/d' file
```

Using `perl`:

```
perl -i.bak -nle 'print unless /^[0-9]{1,9}$/' file
```

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -i.bak -nle 'print unless /^[0-9]{0,9}$/' file
```

You asked for zero length numbers (ie. empty lines) to be removed also.